# pytest: using fixtures in unittest setUp method

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I want to set up a unittest style test class, which uses a pytest fixture in the setUp method. Something like this:

```
def myTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp():
        self.URL = fixture_url

    def test_a():
        # points tests at self.URL
```

It would have a conftest.py file which adds a command line option for the URL. (I have already built this, but I'm not sure how to set up the fixture.)

I want to have multiple test classes testing different features. Then I will run py.test giving a URL which all of the classes will use in their setUp.

If there is some other better way to achieve this I'd be happy to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there's no responses I'll post my makeshift solution:

I created a new file: config.py, which used environment variables to construct the parameters. i.e.

```
# contents of config.py
THIS_URL = os.getenv('TEMP_URL', 'https://www.thisisatest.com')

# contents of test_*.py
...
def setUp(self):
    self.URL = config.THIS_URL
```

This works fine. The environmental variables can be set temporarily from the command line in the normal way.